# A bunch of Errors when converting C# to VB(toast notifcations)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, windows-10, toast

When I converted(using a VB to C# converter, I got alot of errors.

```
    ' Get a toast XML template
    Dim toastXml As XmlDocument = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText04)

    ' Fill in the text elements
    Dim stringElements As XmlNodeList = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text")
    For i As Integer = 0 To stringElements.Length - 1
        stringElements(i).AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Line " + i))
    Next

    ' Specify the absolute path to an image
    Dim imagePath As [String] = "file:///" + Path.GetFullPath("toastImageAndText.png")
    Dim imageElements As XmlNodeList = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image")

    Dim toast As New ToastNotification(toastXml)
```

Here are the errors.

- Value of Type 'XmlDocument' cannot be converted to 'XmlDocument'
- 'Length' is not an member of XmlNodeList
- GetFullPath is not a member of path

Can I get some help on this?
(Edit: Here is the original code:

```
   XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText04);

// Fill in the text elements
XmlNodeList stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
for (int i = 0; i < stringElements.Length; i++)
{
    stringElements[i].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Line " + i));
}

// Specify the absolute path to an image
String imagePath = "file:///" + Path.GetFullPath("toastImageAndText.png");
XmlNodeList imageElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");

ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
```

Comment: You just posted some VB, but said that you are getting errors when you translated your code to C#. Could you clarify?

Comment: 1. Are there possibly two different `XmlDocument` classes being referred to there?  Maybe a name clash?

Comment: 2. Length is indeed not a member of `XmlNodeList`.  `Count` is a member, which makes me think that you actually had an array there in the original code.

Comment: 3. I suspect a name clash due to casing there.  Remember that C# is case-sensitive where VB is not, so `path` and `Path` are different things in C# but the same in VB.